# Disabled button still clickable in IE8 with jQuery.live('click') event

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jquery

Sigh

I keep getting strange problems with IE 8.

I have this

```
    <input name="Btn_Edit" disabled="disabled" id="Btn_Edit" type="button" value="Edit"/>

$(function ()
{
    $('#Btn_Edit').live('click', function ()
    {

        alert('hi');

    });
});
```

So in every other browser this alert would never get trigger as my button is disabled. In IE 8 it goes into my edit button and triggers the alert.

I don't know why.

http://jsfiddle.net/QgceL/

You can see for yourself it. Just load up IE 8 and try it.

However if I change it to this.

http://jsfiddle.net/YD2eS/

It seems to work. I still dont' know why it brings up a different cursor instead of a pointer.

Anyways the problem seems to be with live click event.

Comment: It has to do with the way jQuery handles "live" events.

Comment: Just a comment, as it's not an answer... I didn't realise that jQuery exposed a way to respond to a click on a disabled button ... it'd be quite useful for popping up a message explaining to the user *why* the button they've tried to click is disabled...

Comment: @Rob, you can do this with event bubbling if you detect on the container for an element.  The event.target can give you some information as well under those circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your selector to:

```
$('#Btn_Edit[disabled!=true]')
```

Note that this will NOT work if your selector is $('#Btn_Edit[disabled!=disabled]')

which you can see if you do `alert($('#Btn_Edit').attr('disabled'));` it will be 'false' when it is not disabled and true when it is disabled.

here is a fiddle page to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/QgceL/3/

Comment: ya I sort of did something like that. I instead did if($('#Btn_Edit').attr('disabled') == false) // continue in the actual click event. I am not sure your way is faster though. I also find that confusing I never know if to set .attr('disabled',true) or .attr('disabled','disabled').

Answer (score 0):

Change `live` to `click`.
Yes, it's too weird! I don't know why this happens.

Comment: That's now an option. I have 4 ajax tabs. If a user would go to the next tab and come back the button would not work. For now I guess I have to do a check to see if it is actually disabled or not in the actual click event till someone figure out why this happens.

Comment: You can run event binders each time user clicks in tab, in ajax callback.

Comment: event binders? I am not following

Comment: $("#myId").click(myFunction): i have bind the function myFunction to event click on a element with id 'mID'. You can call $("#myId").click(....) after each ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a jQuery bug, happening in versions < 1.5.x. This post was done probably when jQuery 1.4 was the latest version, but newer versions do not have this problem.